# Calculate Y with new values of X with Neural Network Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, regression

I´m building a neural network regression with Keras, and I need predict the next value of Y with new data input.

i.e. (Historical Data)

- A    B       C       D   E   F       G       H       I
- 0    60  65.0    8450    7   5   2003    2003    196.0   706
- 1    20  80.0    9600    6   8   1976    1976    0.0     978
- 2    60  68.0    11250   7   5   2001    2002    162.0   486
- 3    70  60.0    9550    7   5   1915    1970    0.0     216
- 4    60  84.0    14260   8   5   2000    2000    350.0   655

where: Y(I)= B0 + B1X1 + B2X2 ... [A,B,C,D]
then my neural network model is fitted (model.fit)

My next row with new data input:

- 5    24  43.0    8000    9   10  1200    5000    170     New Value

so, i need predict this new value (empty space) with the new data (24, 43, 8000...) with the trained network (weights...)

how can i do?

Comment: If you have a fitted model then why don't you use `predict` method of that model.

Comment: how will be that code in example? (sorry i´m new in keras)

Comment: Don't be sorry friend :). I am happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predict like so

```
Xnew = [[...], [...]]
test_predictions = model.predict(Xnew)
```

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) is an example